# Jacoco unable to read execution data file in Gradle build

Tags: gradle, jacoco-plugin

I'm using Gradle 6.6.1, and the latest Jacoco plugin version.

With the following in my build file:

```
tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
  executionData(tasks.withType<Test>())
}
```

If I run `gradle buildTests jacocoTestReport` the JacocoTestReport task fails with "unable to read execution data file *projectPath*/build/jacoco/test.exec"

This is because the execution data file is buildTests.exec rather than test.exec.

I was under the impression that passing the tasks to executionData() would result in the correct execution data files to be picked up.

I get the same behaviour if I have the following:

```
tasks.withType<Test>() {
  finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
}


tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
  executionData(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
}
```

Comment: whats the question?